# Backbone JS model fetch not updating attributes automatically

Tags: backbone.js

I'm creating a model to fetch user profile data and then use it but the problem is every time it fetch for data (success response text JSON is available) the model doesn't updated. So I have to set it up manually. This is my code:

```
UserTest = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: {
    userid: null,
    full_name: null,
    photo: null,
    sec_access: null
  },
  urlRoot: 'data/userprofile.php',
  parse: function (response) {
    if (response.photo == null || response.photo == '') response.photo ='images/default-usericon.png';
  }
});

var usertest = new UserTest;
usertest.fetch().then(function(user){
   usertest.set('userid',user.userid);
   usertest.set('full_name',user.full_name);
   usertest.set('photo',user.photo);
   usertest.set('sec_access',user.sec_access);
   console.log(usertest.get('userid'));
});
```

is there a better way? or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: also, you can set multiple attributes by passing an attribute hash to `set`. `usertest.set({userid:user.userid, full_name: user.full_name, /* etc */ })`.

Comment: Or even use [`_.pick`](http://underscorejs.org/#pick): `usertest.set(_.pick(user, 'userid', 'full_name', /* etc */));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the data from `parse`:

```
parse: function (response) {
  if (response.photo == null || response.photo == ''){
    response.photo ='images/default-usericon.png';
  }
  return response; // This is very important
}
```